# Power Query (M Code) - How to replace multiple strings using wildcard

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I need you help figuring out the following.

In Excel (any version) if you go to Replace/Find with as below, all strings between the two characters "<" & ">" will be removed with nothing, no mater how many instances of strings there are.

[image]

This is the example text in a cell:

```
<div class="ExternalClass8E0C57A52828411691835D4E642E1D9B"><p>​MAS hasn't been done or approved by AM, but we've supplied Post PN.</p>
<div>PN Removed: 123456-6A</div>
<div>PN: Installed: Cl123456-6A</div>
<div> A/C: </div>
```

And when Find/Replace is applied to the selected cell, it will clean the html tags and everything in between, so the text in cell will look like this:

```
​MAS hasn't been done or approved by AM, but we've supplied Post PN.
PN Removed: 123456-6A
PN: Installed: Cl123456-6A
AC:
```

How can this be done in Power Query?
I've read a lot of posts on forums, but couldn't find solution to my particular problem.
Maybe i'm missing something, but i can't break my *brain* any longer on this.
There are solutions for replacing strings, but only in one instance, which either clears everything after the first instance or leaves it there with no solution to aggregate on next instance of string.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: see https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Robust-function-to-remove-HTML-tags/td-p/171081 or https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/06/09/removing-html-tags-from-text-in-power-query-power-bi/

Comment: Is `<div A/C: </div></div>` correct?  There are functions to remove tags, but I'm not sure how to apply it here in PQ to get the output you show.  And Excel Replace doesn't give the results you show with `<*>`. In particular, it deletes that line entirely.

Comment: Thanks Ron for replying. You are right, i's not correct, it's just my mistake made by copying/pasting. I've corrected the post.
I'll try out the solutions on the two posts.

Comment: Good to hear.  One of the functions posted by @horseyride works.  The other does not as `Html.Table` seems not to yet have made its way into the Excel O365 version of PQ (at least, not in mine).